# Getting a file's structure's fields/columns

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making my own file extension. I decided to have BinaryReader/BinaryWriter for the loading/saving the file. Now, when I open some file, any file with my file extension, how do I know the structure of it? My Header Structure is basically this:

```
public struct FileHeader
{
    public uint Magic;
    public uint Rows;
    public uint Columns;
    public uint Size;
    public uint Strings;
}
```

Now, this is only the Header file, however, after the Header is loaded/saved, I continue with the saving of all rows. Then, after that, strings saving through bytes. But, in this way, I already know the structure for this file for the rows. So, my question is:

How do I open a file of my file extension, without knowing/declaring the structure before and recognize the Column's Type (int, uint, float, etc.)?

Comment: Usually you would store a record identifying the column types,  widths,  and other information for the row data.

Comment: But the file extension doesn't store that. It doesn't store the column types or anything like that.

Comment: Is it something that is fixed? Type data is not stored when writing binary data with BinaryReader/Writer.

Comment: Well, it could be a: int, uint, float or a string. I only need these. But I can't find a way to do it right. To identify them somehow. :/

Comment: You need to write something to the file first,  like a single byte or a TypeId, like I said,  those don't write any information about the type,  it's just bytes written to the file without type identifiers. If you need type information in the file you'll have to use something like BinarySerializer.

Comment: Alright... Well, the company using this file extension doesn't actually these kind of things.

Comment: After saving the header, save an array of Int32 of the length of number of columns, each Int32 indicates the type of the column. When loading, load the header, then load the "column types array" which you know the length of because it is in the header, then you know for each column it's type. Then proceed to load the data because you know the type of each column.